# Button type reset chama uma função

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

Estou com um formulário web em que eu coloquei um `input type="reset"`, para deletar os dados do formulário caso o usuário precise. O botão funciona e está apagando os dados como desejado, mas estou com um problema.

Eu tenho um `select`, em que dependendo do valor que eu seleciono nele, ele muda o conteúdo, e o `select` está dentro do form. O select vem com um valor padrão em que não aparece conteúdo nenhum.

Quando eu clico no botão de reset, ele volta o `select` ao valor padrão e o conteúdo não some, como esperado. Vou deixar um exemplo:

```js
function mostrarConteudo(){
  if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "Nao"){
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "";
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  mostrarConteudo();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <select id="sel" class="form-control w-100" onchange="mostrarConteudo()">
    <option value"">Nao</option>
    <option value"S">Sim</option>
  </select>
  
  <br>
  
  <div id="div" style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="ml-4">Valor da div</div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <button type="reset">Resetar Form</button>
</form>
```

Repare que ao deixar o select com a opção "sim" e resetar, ele troca o valor para "nao", mas a div nao some.

Já tentei colocar no select um `onreset` para chamar novamente a função mas não funcionou.

Já tentei colocar um `onclick` no botão, também não funcionou.

Oque eu posso fazer para corrigir este erro?

**EDIT:**

Erro quando tento passar um parâmetro, como sugerido na resposta do Sam: (no caso, minha função se chama `openOptions()`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214564/html-form-reset-not-doing-triggering-select-onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um atributo `onclick` chamando a função e passando qualquer valor:

```
<button type="reset" onclick="mostrarConteudo(this)">Resetar Form</button>
```

Se o valor do parâmetro passado existir na função, significa que o botão reset foi clicado:

```js
function mostrarConteudo(e){
                    //   ↑----------------------------↓
  if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "Nao" || e){
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "";
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  mostrarConteudo();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="sel" class="form-control w-100" onchange="mostrarConteudo()">
    <option value"">Nao</option>
    <option value"S">Sim</option>
  </select>
  
  <br>
  
  <div id="div" style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="ml-4">Valor da div</div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <button type="reset" onclick="mostrarConteudo(this)">Resetar Form</button>
</form>
```

---

Pode também esconder o elemento direto no `onclick`, sem passar pela função:

```
<button type="reset" onclick="$('#div').hide()">Resetar Form</button>
```

---

Outra forma é criar um *event listener* pro botão e chamar a função após um pequeno atraso usando `setTimeout()`:

```js
function mostrarConteudo(){
  if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "Nao"){
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "";
  }
}

$("[type=reset]").on("click", function(){
   setTimeout(mostrarConteudo, 1);
});

window.onload = function () {
  mostrarConteudo();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="sel" class="form-control w-100" onchange="mostrarConteudo()">
    <option value"">Nao</option>
    <option value"S">Sim</option>
  </select>
  
  <br>
  
  <div id="div" style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="ml-4">Valor da div</div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <button type="reset">Resetar Form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Para o meu código, isso nao seria possivel, pois tem lugares no próprio js em que eu preciso chamar a função(como no `window.onload`), mas no meu código esta dando erro quando eu chamo, por nao passar nenhum parametro.

Comment: Se não passar nenhum parâmetro, o `e` é _undefined_ e não dá erro não. Mas adicionei àresposta outra solução.

Comment: como dito no comentário da resposta ao Hugo, o ideal é que eu chame a função, como no seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Vou deixar um print na pergunta com o erro

Comment: Adiconei outra forma no final da resposta. Existem 1 milhão de maneiras de fazer isso rs

Comment: opa, agora sim. A sua última resposta funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Altera o select do HTML para que os valores sejam por exemplo 1 e 2 e o botão type reset coloca type button e com um onclick a chamar a função resetForm()

Options dentro do select:

```
<option value"1">Nao</option>
<option value"2">Sim</option>
```

Botão de reset:

```
<button type="button" onclick="resetForm()">Resetar Form</button>
```

Depois no JS na estrutura de decisão da função mostrarConteudo:

```
if(document.getElementById("sel").value == 1){
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
}else{
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "";
}
```

Esta é uma nova função para resetar o fomulário:

```
function resetForm(){
    document.getElementById('sel').value = 1;
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
}
```

Isto deverá resolver o teu problema

Answer (score -1):

É fácil...
O js não volta a chamar a função "mostrarConteudo" porque só é chamada cada vez que der reload na página.
Ou seja o problema é esse a função não é chamada depois.

Comment: e como eu a chamo depois de resetar ?

Comment: <option value"">Nao</option> isso está errado! Verifica isso ... value='nao'

Answer (score -2):

```js
function calcular() {


let n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('nt1').value)

let n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('nt2').value)

let n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('nt3').value)

let n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('nt4').value)

let resultado = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4
  
document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = ('A média é: ') + resultado

}

function limpar() {
     document.getElementById('nt1').value = null
document.getElementById('nt2').value = null
document.getElementById('nt3').value = null
document.getElementById('nt4').value = null  
  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.titulo {
  color: rgb(245,245,245);
  background-color: rgb(105,89,205);
  text-align: center;
  font-stretch: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%,  rgba(0,221,214,1) 0%, rgba(51,102,255,1) 90% );
}

.area {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

input {
  height: 10%;
  width: 20%;
}

div {
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.bts {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#resultado {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  
}

.base {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <title>Média Escolar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="titulo">
    <h1>Média Escolar</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="area">
    <form>
      <div><label>Nota 1</label>

        <input type="number" id="nt1" />

      </div>

      <div><label>Nota 2</label>

        <input type="number" id="nt2" />

      </div>

      <div><label>Nota 3</label>

        <input type="number" id="nt3" />

      </div>

      <div><label>Nota 4</label>

        <input type="number" id="nt4" />

    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="bts">

    <input id="btc" type="button" onclick="calcular()" value="Calcular" />

    <input id="btl" type="button" onclick="limpar()" value="Limpar" />

  </div>
  <div id="resultado">
  </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Não sei se é a mesma coisa. Já que sou novo ainda nesse mundo.
Mas eu fiz dessa forma aqui. Atribuindo ao botão que limpa o formulário.

```js
function limpar() {
     document.getElementById('nt1').value = null
document.getElementById('nt2').value = null
document.getElementById('nt3').value = null
document.getElementById('nt4').value = null  
  
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).